# I want the result of my query should be without the time and only date will be shown in result

Tags: soql, datetime

```
Select Id, CreatedDate From Opportunity Where DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate)
```

this the query I used but result is still with time

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce SOQL query doesn't provide a function to convert and display from Datetime to Date.

You could create formula Date field and convert datetime to date as follows:
`DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)`

And, use that formula field in the SOQL query.

Comment: But what if I am using thing on an standard object

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation on Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) isn't very clear about this limitation, but you can only ignore the time value when doing an aggregate query. This function cannot return the date value only for individual records, but it can for groupings.

This query works:

```
SELECT DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) FROM Opportunity GROUP BY DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate)
```

But this query fails:

```
SELECT DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) FROM Opportunity
```

With this error:

> Date-aggregate functions can only be selected in grouped queries